# How to store a value of prop in a variable and then access it in react?

Tags: json, ajax, reactjs, axios

I am using cdn for react

Actually I have two JSON FILE,

abc.json

```
[
    {
      "apiKey":"642176ece1e7445e99244cec26f4de1f"
    }
]
```

reactjs.json

```
[
    {
        "642176ece1e7445e99244cec26f4de1f": {
                "src": "image_1.jpg",
                "id" : "1"

            }
    }
]
```

I actually want that first of all I get apiKey from the first json file and after with the help of it i like to get the value of src

1) How can I do this in React using axios?
2) Is that Possible that we can directly get the src from reactjs.json ? If yes then How?

What I tried, but it gives error..

```
class FetchDemo extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);

          this.state = {
          images: [],
          api:[]
          };

          //this.listImages = this.listImages.bind(this);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
          axios.get('abc.json').then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({ api: res.data });
          });
          axios.get('reactjs.json').then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({ images: res.data });
          });
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              {this.state.api.map((api, index) => (
                <Pictures key={index} apikeys={api.apiKey} />
              ))}
            </div>
          );
        }

      }

      class Pictures extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return (
            <h1>
              alt={this.props.apikeys}
            </h1>
            {this.state.images.map((images, index) => (
                <h1 key={index}> apikeys={images.+`{this.props.apikeys}`+.src} </h1>
//Error at this point
            ))}
          );
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(
        <FetchDemo/>,
        document.getElementById("root")
      );
```

Comment: Are you using webpack? You could just import your JSON files instead if that's the case. Your JSON is also arrays with one object in it. It looks like you could just make them into objects directly to make it easier for yourself.

Comment: I actually want that first of all I get apiKey from the first json file and after with the help of it i like to get the value of src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using axios you are making a request. This means that your JSON would be served from a end point. If you really need to require the json file in this fashion try importing

```
import abc from './abc.json';

componentDidMount = () => {
 this.setState({
 json: abc 
 })
}
```

Comment: I am using cdn for react

Comment: I actually want that first of all I get apiKey from the first json file and after with the help of it i like to get the value of src from second json file